# solve: $x=(x^2-2y+1)y' $ for both x(y) and y(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

this might be a tricky one:
solve: $x=(x^2-2y+1)y' $ for both x(y) and y(x)

I believe that x is a regular Bernoulli (just take the inverse of y' and you get x*x').
but the other one is much more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=(x^2-2y+1)y' = (x^2-2y+1) \frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\Rightarrow x\frac{dx}{dy} = (x^2-2y+1) $$
Consider $x'$ instead of $y'$
$$\Rightarrow xx'=(x^2-2y+1)$$
$$\frac 12 (x^2)'=(x^2-2y+1)$$
Substitute $v=x^2$
$$\frac 12 v'=(v-2y+1)$$
$$ v'-2v=2(1-2y)$$
$$ (ve^{-2y})'=2(1-2y)e^{-2y}$$
Integrate.
$$x^2=2y+ke^{2y}$$
$$e^{x^2}=e^{2y+ke^{2y}}$$
$$ke^{x^2}=ke^{2y+ke^{2y}}$$
$$W(ke^{x^2})=ke^{2y}$$
$$W(ke^{x^2})=x^2-2y$$
Finally:
$$\boxed { y(x)=\frac 12 \left (x^2-W(ke^{x^2})\right )}$$
Where $W$ is the Lambert's function.

Comment: yes this one I was able to solve, the hard question is with regarding to y. thanks

Comment: @peru yw...Did you get the final answer ?

Comment: I got the the answer regarding x(y), but y(x) I wasn't able to solve.

Comment: @pery sometimes you keep the solution in implicit form

Comment: actually it seems that WA has managed to find something:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D%28x%5E2-2y%2B1%29y%27

Comment: @peru  you can use Lambert's Function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @peru I added some lines ...Same solution as WA

Comment: @Alt thanks for the correction and edit

Comment: thank you very much!